# mousedown not working

Tags: jquery

With the below code, when i click and hold the `bid-up` button, it only goes through the code once and i have to click again for it to work.  What it should do is it repeat the code until mouseup or mouseleave. What did i do wrong?

```
$('.bid-up').live('mousedown',function() {

    var button = $(this);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){

        var number = button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val();
        var newnumber = number.split('.');
        var on = button.attr('data-on');

        button.siblings('#bid-down').attr('data-on','1');

        if(newnumber[1]<9) {
            var first = newnumber[0];
            var second = parseInt(newnumber[1])+1;
        }

        if(newnumber[1]==9) {
            var first = parseInt(newnumber[0])+1;
            var second = 0;
        }

        var finalnumber = first+'.'+second;
        button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val(finalnumber);

    }, 20);

}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

Comment: I think it will go through only once, because you are using `setTimeout`

Comment: Consider storing the timeout in `.data()` instead of a global variable: `button.data('timeout', setTimeout(...));` and `clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'))`

Answer (score 2):

Solution: use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` instead of timeout, because setTimeout only executes the closure function once, or `setTimeout` in your closure function.

Example for using `setTimeout` in the function itself:

```
$('.bid-up').live('mousedown',function() {

    var button = $(this);


    function asd(){

        var number = button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val();
        var newnumber = number.split('.');
        var on = button.attr('data-on');

        button.siblings('#bid-down').attr('data-on','1');

        if(newnumber[1]<9) {
        var first = newnumber[0];
        var second = parseInt(newnumber[1])+1;
        }

        if(newnumber[1]==9) {
        var first = parseInt(newnumber[0])+1;
        var second = 0;
        }

        var finalnumber = first+'.'+second;
        button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val(finalnumber);

        timeoutId = setTimeout(asd, 20);
    }

    timeoutId = setTimeout(asd, 20);

}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
```

example using `setInterval` and [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store interval id.

```
$('.bid-up').live('mousedown',function() {

    var button = $(this);

    button.data('interval', setInterval(function (){

        var number = button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val();
        var newnumber = number.split('.');
        var on = button.attr('data-on');

        button.siblings('#bid-down').attr('data-on','1');

        if(newnumber[1]<9) {
        var first = newnumber[0];
        var second = parseInt(newnumber[1])+1;
        }

        if(newnumber[1]==9) {
        var first = parseInt(newnumber[0])+1;
        var second = 0;
        }

        var finalnumber = first+'.'+second;
        button.parent('div').siblings('#bid-child-container-2').find('#bid-price').val(finalnumber);
    }, 20));

}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(button.data('interval'));
});
```

Comment: thanks it works but when i mouseup or mouseleave it doesn't stop.  It keeps on going?  any idea why?

Comment: Which one did you use? Also consider storing the timeout in .data() instead of a global variable: `button.data('timeout', setTimeout(...));` and `clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'))` I think your `timeoutId` is not defined on `mouseup mouseleave`

Comment: what do you get if you `alert(timeoutId);` after `clearInterval(timeoutId);`?

Comment: I updated the code to use `.data` could you try again please? But it is interesting that the alert doesn't even appear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11795/discussion-between-19greg96-and-user892134)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
    http://jsfiddle.net/R85Xb/

```
var timeoutId;
function x()
{
        $("#bids").append("x");
        timeoutId = setTimeout(x, 200);
}

$('.bid-up').live('mousedown', function() {

    var button = $(this);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(x, 200);

}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
    //alert('clear');
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});​


<div class="bid-up">here</div>
<div id="bids"></div>​
```